# Get the value/description from a domain or subtype for a given field's value?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I need to get a value from an IObject.Fields.Field using ArcObjects 10.x using the criteria listed below:

1. If the field has a subtype associated with it, I need to get the
   subtype name/description based on the field value.
2. If the field has a coded value domain associated with it, I need to
   get the domain's name/description based on the field value.
3. If the field has neither a subtype or domain associated with it, I
   want the field value itself returned.
4. Having this functionality wrapped up in one call like "ReadFieldValue(IObject obj, int fieldIndex) is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is what I came up with:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the field value from the IObject.  Checks for coded
    /// value domains, subtypes, or just the plain field value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">ESRI IObject</param>
    /// <param name="fieldIndex">Field index for the IObject.Fields.Field</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static object ReadFieldValue(IObject obj, int fieldIndex, bool ignoreDescription = false)
    {
        object fieldValue = null;

        if (obj != null && fieldIndex > -1)
        {
            /// Default to the field value first,
            /// overwrite it if a subtype or domain
            /// is found.
            fieldValue = obj.Value[fieldIndex];
        if (fieldValue != DBNull.Value && ignoreDescription == false)
        {
            ISubtypes subtypes = obj.Class as ISubtypes;
            IRowSubtypes rowSubtypes = obj as IRowSubtypes;
            IField2 field = obj.Fields.Field[fieldIndex] as IField2;

            // Set the appropriate domain based on the subtype if a subtype exists.
            IDomain domain = null;
            if (field != null)
            {
                if (subtypes != null && subtypes.SubtypeFieldIndex > -1)
                {
                    domain = subtypes.get_Domain(rowSubtypes.SubtypeCode, field.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    domain = field.Domain;
                }
            }

            // Check for a subtype field first
            if (subtypes != null && rowSubtypes != null && subtypes.SubtypeFieldIndex == fieldIndex)
                fieldValue = subtypes.get_SubtypeName(rowSubtypes.SubtypeCode);
            // If it is not a subtype field, check for a domain field
            else if (domain != null)
            {
                ICodedValueDomain2 cvDomain = domain as ICodedValueDomain2;
                if (cvDomain != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cvDomain.CodeCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (cvDomain.get_Value(i).Equals(fieldValue))
                        {
                            fieldValue = cvDomain.get_Name(i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
        return fieldValue;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? It looks fine to me. You can get the domains from the ISubtypes, but only if the feature/object class has a subtype to begin with.

Comment: I assumed nothing was wrong with this approach, but you never know if something better exists. :)