# How can I get domain values associated with a field using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, domains

I am trying to access the domain of a selected feature.  I have seen examples for [VB.NET](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_and_modifying_domains/0001000003mt000000/) and [C#.NET](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152967/get-the-value-description-from-a-domain-or-subtype-for-a-given-fields-value), but I cannot access the domain of a specified field.

```
Dim findName As String = Nothing
Dim findValue As Integer = 21 'the domain value for AGRICULTURE
Dim fieldIndex As Integer = m_Feature.Fields.Field("my_field") 'this has a coded domain

'--Check for my_field
If fieldIndex <> -1 Then
    Dim domain As IDomain = m_Feature.Field(fieldIndex).Domain
    If domain.Type = esriDomainType.esriDTCodedValue Then
        Dim cvDomain As ICodedValueDomain2 = TryCast(domain, ICodedValueDomain2)
        For i = 0 To cvDomain.CodeCount - 1
            If cvDomain.Value(i).Equals(findValue) Then
                findName = cvDomain.Name(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
```

When debugging it hangs up on the line with domain.Type, and it shows that the value of Domain is Nothing.  The [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000033v000000) shows that IField.Domain should return the default domain as an IDomain object.  I know the field has a domain, but I don't know if it is default and am unable to change it.  Does anyone have any advice on how I should access the domain of a field  (of a selected feature in my case)?

Comment: Are you sure the field has a domain associated? Domains can also be specified only for a particular subtype.

Comment: @PetrKrebs The featureclass has subtypes, and the field in question can have different domains depending on subtype.

Comment: Right.. so you need to retrieve the domain for a specific field and a specific subtype (see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000871000000). The default domain will probably not make much sense in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Petr's comments, I found the solution.  Below is my functioning code.

```
Dim findName As String = Nothing
Dim findValue As Integer = 21 'the domain value for AGRICULTURE
Dim fieldIndex As Integer = m_Feature.Fields.Field("my_field") 'this has a coded domain
Dim subfieldIndex As Integer = m_Feature.Fields.FindField("subfield") 'index of subtype field
Dim subfield As Integer = m_Feature.Value(subfieldIndex) 'value of subtype field  

'--Check for my_field
If fieldIndex <> -1 Then

    Dim subtypes As ISubtypes = TryCast(m_Feature.Class, ISubtypes)
    Dim domain As IDomain = subtypes.Domain(subfield, "my_field")

    If domain.Type = esriDomainType.esriDTCodedValue Then
        Dim cvDomain As ICodedValueDomain2 = TryCast(domain, ICodedValueDomain2)
        For i = 0 To cvDomain.CodeCount - 1
            If cvDomain.Value(i).Equals(findValue) Then
                findName = cvDomain.Name(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the answer